# Is a collection of pairwise disjoint closed intervals countable?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Attempt:** If we argue the same way as we did for the case of open intervals: Since the closed intervals are disjoint, we can identify each closed interval with a rational number in that interval and since the rationals are countable, their subsets are countable as well. Hence, the collection of disjoint closed intervals must be countable as well.

I just read somewhere that the disjoint collection of closed intervals in $\Bbb R$ may not be  countable. But, Is there an error in the above argument?

Comment: Is $[x,x]$ a closed interval?

Comment: If singletons like $[x,x]=\{x\}$ count as closed intervals, then the answer is clearly no. If singletons do not count then the answer is yes since the collection of interiors of those closed intervals will be a collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals and must therefore be countable (note that two closed intervals are equal iff their interiors are equal).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks got it.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks. got it. if you would like to make it an answer, i will accept it

Comment: @MathMan Also, the reasoning you gave also works when we don't count singletons as closed intervals since then every closed interval contains a rational number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment:

If singletons do not count then the answer is yes since the collection of interiors of those closed intervals will be a collection of pairwise disjoint open intervals and must therefore be countable (note that $[a,b]=[c,d]$ if and only if $(a,b)=(c,d)$).